# Calculus maple for chapter differentiation

Tags: calculus, math-software, maple

Anyone knows what's right the command for the question:

y = 4x - √x + (1/^3√x^2)

The answer supposed to be:

4 - (1/2√x) - (2/3x^5/3)l

But my answer is:
4 - (1/2√x) - (2/3)(x/(x^2)^4/3)

I suppose my answer is right or the answer that given to me is wrong.)

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange.  Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) to improve legibility

Comment: Assuming I parsed your expression correctly, they are both equivalent correct answers.

Comment: In maple, the command for symbolic differentiation in one variable is diff(f(x),x)

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your expression is $y=4x-\sqrt{x}+\frac{1}{x^\frac{2}{3}}$. Differentiating gives $y'=4-\frac{1}{2\sqrt{x}}-\frac{2}{3x^\frac{5}{3}}$. This is equivalent to your expression since $\frac{x}{(x^2)^\frac{4}{3}}=\frac{1}{x^{\frac{4}{3}-1}}=\frac{1}{x^\frac{5}{3}}$.

In Maple, this is diff(4*x-x^(1/2)+x^(-2/3),x)